# Imagemagick Mogrify crop output name

Tags: imagemagick, filenames, crop, mogrify

When using `mogrify -crop 500x500 *.jpg`

I get output as `*-1.jpg, *-2.jpg, *-3.jpg, *-4.jpg`

Is it possible to change so that it gets a different separator. eg. underscore?

output: `*_1.jpg, *_2.jpg, *_3.jpg, *_4.jpg,`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with `convert`:

```
convert *.jpg -crop 500x500 -set filename:f "%t_%p" '%[filename:f].jpg'
```

See [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) for more info.

Comment: And the `set` option is [described here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set).

Comment: Not sure why, but using that command line I get the result on a *_-1.jpg form instead of a *_1.jpg form. Does anyone know how to get rid of the '-'?